# Partitioning a convex $n$-polygon

Tags: co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, partitions, polygons

Let $P$ be a convex polygon with $n\ge3$ vertices. Let $\mathcal{Z}_K(P)$ be a partition of the polygon into $K$ polygonal (but not necessarily convex) parts whose interiors are pairwise disjoint,
$$
\mathcal{Z}_K(P)=\{p_1,\ldots,p_K\}\quad\text{s.t.}\quad \operatorname{int}(p_i) \cap \operatorname{int}(p_j)=\emptyset\;\forall i\neq j\quad\wedge\quad \bigcup_{i=1}^K p_i=P.
$$

> **Question.** Is it true for every $K$, that there is such a partition $\mathcal{Z}_K(P)$ that allows all parts $p_i$ to share at least one edge or vertex with every other part $p_{j\neq i}$?

I tried for $n=4$ and $K=2,3,4$ and succeeded (trivial), but I got stuck at $K=5$. I tried to search for this specific partitioning but I couldn't find anything relevant.

I only found out that if we let $k_i$ be the centroid of the i-th part $p_i$, and connect such centroid to all other centroids $k_{j\neq i}$ of polygonal parts that share at least one edge or vertex with every other part, the resulting graph will have an all-ones adjacency matrix.

Comment: Could you clarify your notation slightly? I believe you want to specify that the $p_i$ are pairwise disjoint, instead of saying the intersection of all of them is empty. Also I get confused by what is a "part", what is "partition" and what is "partitioning". Are $p_i$ polygonal parts (subsets) of $P$? Is ${\cal Z}_K(P)$ a partition into $K$ such polygonal parts, as your notation says, or is it the set of all such partitions?

Comment: Why is this not a solution? Let $x$ be any strictly interior point of $P$. Draw spokes from $x$ to the boundary of $P$, with adjacent spokes separated by $2 \pi /K$. The resulting pieces $p_i$ each share $x$.

Comment: Let $P=S^n$ be the boundary of an $(n+1)$-simplex. The intersection of the $n+2$ main faces is empty, the union is the entire $S^n$, and every two intersect at their common $(n-1)$-dimensional face.

Comment: Wait, for $K=2$ the intersection of parts must be empty but they should have a common edge or vertex. How is this possible?

Comment: Fedor, my guess is the OP means that their interiors must have empty intersection. This is another thing that should be clarified in the question.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Terribly sorry. I'll clarify right away: YES $p_i$s are pairwise disjoint, and YES $p_i$s are poligonal parts (subsets) of $P$, and $\mathcal{Z}_K(P)$ is a partition into $K$ parts and NOT the set of all such partitions

Comment: @JukkaKohonen I've edited my question. I apologize for the bad writing, and I hope I clarified a bit. I could add some diagrams if it helps to drive the point of my question home

Comment: Thanks, it is clearer now. Is it also so that the INTERIORS of the parts must be pairwise disjoint? (Otherwise surely they cannot share a vertex or an edge.) Still it seems Joseph's comment would provide an easy solution, so is this what you are after, or something else?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Absolutely yes, and I'm trying to visualize Joseph solution, I'll tell in the comments asap. If that works, it surely will be a neat answer!

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Yep, yours is a solution, as the partition share the central vertex $x$. I should add another question with a stricter requirement, that all $p_i$ must share at least one *edge* with all other parts.

Comment: In this case, for $K=5$ you will get an embedding of $K_5$ in the plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to follow up @IlyaBogdanov's observation: a $k=4$ partition, whose
pieces pairwise share an edge, can be achieved (below), corresponding to a planar embedding of $K_4$.
But realizing the same for $k=5$ would
would lead to planar embedding of $K_5$, which is impossible.

---

[image: K4]